# Send mail using custom button created using inboxsdk?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api, gmail-addons, inboxsdk

I am creating chrome extension for gmail, 
I want send a mail when user click a button created by my extension. I am using inboxsdk for creating extension.

I am creating button using following code

```
InboxSDK.load('1', '**************').then(function(sdk){
    // the SDK has been loaded, now do something with it!
    sdk.Compose.registerComposeViewHandler(function(composeView){

        // a compose view has come into existence, do something with it!
        composeView.addButton({
            title: "button-title-goes",
            iconUrl: 'https://image.ibb.co/mXS2ZU/images.png',
            onClick: function(event) {
                console.log( event );
                event.composeView.insertHTMLIntoBodyAtCursor('<img src="https://image.ibb.co/mXS2ZU/images.png" alt="Smiley face" height="1" width="1">');
            },
        });

    });
});
```

I want to send mail when user click on this button.

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468422/how-do-we-add-new-button-to-gmail-compose-bar-in-chrome-extension-is-it-through)?

Comment: Yes, but no use from that SO post.

Comment: You can try `send(sendOptions)` method of the `ComposeView` class of `InboxSDK`. The doc describes the above method as `Simulates clicking the compose's send button.`. Here is the [link](https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/#ComposeView) to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the compose views `send()` function like follows.

```
sdk.Compose.registerComposeViewHandler(function(composeView){
    composeView.addButton({
        title: "button-title-goes",
        iconUrl: 'https://image.ibb.co/mXS2ZU/images.png',
        onClick: function(event) {
            console.log( event );
            event.composeView.insertHTMLIntoBodyAtCursor('<img src="https://image.ibb.co/mXS2ZU/images.png" alt="Smiley face" height="1" width="1">');
            composeView.send();
        },
    });

});
```

You can even hand over an optional configuration object which allows you to send and archive.
[InboxSDK - ComposeView](https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/#ComposeView)