# How to add action to the button created using inboxsdk in gmail inbox?

Tags: popup, gmail, action, inboxsdk

I have created the button in the gmail inbox using inboxsdk.
Now i want to get a pop up by clicking on that button

2.Pop up should contain a link which navigates to my website page(xyz.com/login.php)

How can i do these using inboxsdk

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you are still struggling with this, I would suggest a simple solution which is to fire a JavaScript confirm dialog [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973240/link-in-alert-boxes-javascript). On confirmation you could redirect the user, using `window.location.href = '<your-url>';`.

Another solution would be to use InboxSDK's [widgets](https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/#Widgets).
Example:

```
InboxSDK.load(2, '<InboxSDK-app-id>').then((sdk) => {
  ...
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = '<a href="<your-url>" target="_blank">Link description</a>';

  sdk.Widget.showModalView({
    title: 'Modal Title',
    el
  });
});
```

For more `ModalOptions` look [here](https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/#ModalOptions).

**Notice**: I set the attribute `target` attribute of `<a>` tag to `"_blank"`. This makes sure the url opens in another browser tab.

A third, more direct (optional) solution would be to add an `onClick` event listener to which you attach a function that redirects the user to your url, see a code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813263/send-mail-using-custom-button-created-using-inboxsdk).

A fourth and better possible solution would be to add a `DropdownView` to your button's `onClick` function, see example code [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/inboxsdk/4YlLWum_CKI).